# Append list to list and save it

Tags: python

Todo code, show your tasks, can add and delete task.
the tasks have date, name, status, and urgency(low, mid, high)

so I wrote a Todo program, I have tasks.

```
task1 = ['task 1', '2-4-2022', 'mid', True]
task2 = ['task 2', '2-4-2022', 'mid', True]
task3 = ['task 3', '2-4-2022', 'mid', True]

tasks = [task1, task2, task3]
```

I have this function that adds tasks.

```
def create_task(tasks, task_name, task_date):
    list1 = []
    list1.append(task_name)
    list1.append(task_date)
    tasks.append(list1)
    return tasks
```

and function that remove them

```
def remove_task(tasks, task_name):
    for i in range(len(tasks)):
        if tasks[i][0] == task_name:
            tasks.pop(i)
            break
```

this is checks the date and make sure it is valid.

```
date = "2-4-2022"
date2 = "12-3-2022"
date3 = "2-12-2022"
len_date = len(date)
date_hidden = (len_date * "_")
len_date2 = len(date2)
date2_hidden = (len_date2 * "_")
len_date3 = len(date3)
date3_hidden = (len_date2 * "_")
```

but when you add task you can only add one, if you add more it delete the previous one.

how do I save the tasks I add

```
start_question = input("What whould you like to do?\t1.Delete task\t2.Create task")
if start_question == "1":
    which_task = input("Which task would you like to delete?")
    if which_task == "task1":
        remove_task(tasks, 'task 1')
        print("Task successfully deleted")
        print(tasks)
if start_question == "2":
    what_name = input("What is the task name?")
    task_name = what_name
    what_date = input("What is the date for the task to end?")
    task_date = what_date
    task_date2 = what_date
    len_task_date = len(task_date)
    len_task_date2 = len(task_date2)
    if (len_task_date * "_") or (len_task_date2 * "_") == date_hidden:
       task_date = what_date
       task_date2 = what_date
       create_task(tasks, what_name, what_date)
       print(tasks)
```

Comment: Please show a complete example of using the functions, that can be run without typing user input; show exactly what you expect to happen, and exactly what does happen instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more details and guidance.

Comment: use dictionary in this use case not list, and in that dict you can add the task details as dict too which make it is easy to traverse and add and easy to maintain compare to list

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you are always defining

```
tasks = [task1, task2, task3]
```

Therefore it seems like you can only add one task, but if you don't run that part of the code once it's initialized it should work.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

as I see the task variable you are appending to is the one inside your function.
the lifecycle of a variable inside a function is just in its own scope.
you are returning the new task variable inside the function but you should store it in your global task variable that is outside of your function

```
import sys

tasks = []

date = "2-4-2022"
date2 = "12-3-2022"
date3 = "2-12-2022"
len_date = len(date)
date_hidden = (len_date * "_")
len_date2 = len(date2)
date2_hidden = (len_date2 * "_")
len_date3 = len(date3)
date3_hidden = (len_date2 * "_")


def create_task(tasks, task_name, task_date):
    list1 = []
    list1.append(task_name)
    list1.append(task_date)
    tasks.append(list1)
    return tasks


def remove_task(tasks, task_name):
    for i in range(len(tasks)):
        if tasks[i][0] == task_name:
            tasks.pop(i)
            break
    return tasks


while True:
    if tasks:
        print("Tasks to do  : \n")
        for n, i in enumerate(tasks):
            print("{} : ".format(n), i)
    start_question = input("What whould you like to do?\t1.Delete task\t2.Create task\t3.Exit app")
    if start_question == "1":
        which_task = input("Which task would you like to delete? \n")
        tasks = remove_task(tasks, which_task)
        print("Task successfully deleted")
    if start_question == "2":
        what_name = input("What is the task name? \n")
        task_name = what_name
        what_date = input("What is the date for the task to end? \n")
        task_date = what_date
        task_date2 = what_date
        len_task_date = len(task_date)
        len_task_date2 = len(task_date2)
        if (len_task_date * "_") or (len_task_date2 * "_") == date_hidden:
            task_date = what_date
            task_date2 = what_date
            tasks = create_task(tasks, what_name, what_date)

    if start_question == "3":
        sys.exit(0)  # Compeletly close your program
```

But the better way is when you want to repeatedly change a variable that is used in many functions try to create a class and use functions as a class method and change the "tasks" property of that class

Comment: it still doesnt work

Comment: did you create a variable named "tasks" outside of your if statement?

Comment: yes, and still doesnt work

Comment: I have created a python file like the code above from your own code and it's working and changed my answer to the tested one! check the differences from your own example ;)